# How to find out who is connected to my Android over adb?

Tags: android, ip, adb

We have several rooted android devices on our network and different computers may have open adb connects to them at various times.  The problem is that when someone tries to connect and another computer is already connected it comes up as offline and the connection cannot be established until the other computer disconnects.  Even after power cycling the device the connection remains.  It is super frustrating and interferes with productivity when we have to stop working and ask around for who might be connected.

To solve this problem I would like the device to be able to kill all open connections to it.  Short of that I would like the device to be able to report the IP address of the connected computer.  Is it possible to get this information from the android side?  If so I can write into our application a call that returns the culprit IP address.

Alternatively is there a way to have adb log the connection events to logcat where I can later pick them up?

Comment: What about disabling and re-enabling adb on the device does that has an effect? Note that "connected" in the adb context does not imply there is an active TCP connection. Otherwise you could simply execute `netstat` to see the active adb connection. Therefore I assume the IP of the connected computer is irrelevant, instead the used adb authentication key is what makes you "connected". If you are a group of coequal programmers using only "group owned" devices you could try to share the adb authentication key among each other.

Comment: Interesting.  I have tried both those aproaches but you probably know more about netstat than I do.  disabling and reenabling adb from the device side has no effect because the PC is the one that maintains the connetion and remains connected after I do that.  Through netstat I can see the adb process but it doesn't list the IP of the computer that's connected.  But this authentication key might help.  Would it allow multiple PC's to connect at the same time?